# remove all other shipping method if there's a method having shipping amount zero

Tags: magento

Could it be possible to remove all the `shipping methods` except the one having shipping amount **0**?

There may be a `promotion rule` which will return the amount **0** for shipping, so it must not be removed.

[image: conditional free shipping]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880574/remove-shipping-methods-completely-from-magento

Comment: @himansu: not a good link. I'd done it by myself. and will post answer after a while

Comment: possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14817516/remove-shipping-option-if-condition-is-met?rq=1 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12950737/magento-remove-shipping-handling-when-using-freeshipping?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Display only shipping methods with price 0 (zero) if any](http://ermohammadfaisal.wordpress.com/2014/04/07/display-only-shipping-methods-with-price-0-zero-if-any/)

In my module I'd overridden the `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available` block as:

**config.xml**

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <checkout>
            <rewrite>
                <onepage_shipping_method_available>Excellence_Subscription_Block_Checkout_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available</onepage_shipping_method_available>
            </rewrite>
        </checkout>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

**Excellence_Subscription_Block_Checkout_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available**

```
<?php

class Excellence_Subscription_Block_Checkout_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available {

    public function getShippingRates() {
        $groups = parent::getShippingRates();
        $free = array();
        foreach ($groups as $code => $_rates) {
            foreach ($_rates as $_rate) {
                if (!$_rate->getPrice() > 0) {
                    $free[$code] = $_rates;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!empty($free)) {
            return $this->_rates = $free;
        }
        return $groups;
    }

}
```

Comment: This is working for only if there is product in the cart over the set price for free shipping. Otherwise, it shows all the available methods. Any help?

Comment: I think it should be working with all shipping method (if any) returns `0`.

Comment: That will only hide the method and will not bypass the internal calculation.

Comment: @DushyantJoshi: yes. do you have any other solution?

Comment: @MohammadFaisal, in `collectRates` method?